# Why is current admin not shown in django app?

Tags: python, django

I created a mock user profile in Django admin in the **admin/auth/user**
view and assigned the user with all permissions (active, staff status, superuser status). In **admin/<app_name>/user** I gave the user all authorization permissions. This user was created to test different permissions set for them on the admin panel. I have verified that this user model was created.

In the Django admin panel with the mock user, when I hit view site and enter the home view of the django application, the post request to the home page returns a different user as opposed to the current admin. Why is the HTTP request rendering a different user instead of the admin user? In the following example, my Admin site welcomes the mock user I created (**Test**), but when I click 'View Site' the user is different from the 'Test' user. I only have 2 users created for the Django app.

[image: Admin User (Test) Greeted in Django Admin Panel]

[image: Clicking "View Site" a different user is permitted (blacked out)]

Comment: how do you know user is diffrent?

Comment: @shivankgtm the home view prints out a different user name. In the bottom image, i blacked out the user name but it says 'permissions for (user name)'. Additionally, the email/logon information of the user is printed on the home view and it does not match that of the 'test' users info